# Jenkins jobs on slaves keep on losing the “PATH” environment variables values

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

My Jenkins jobs on slaves keep on losing the “PATH” environment variables values. I am setting a path variable on my slave configuration in such a way:
[image]
The issue is, my jobs running on this slave keep on loosing their environment values and keep on getting erros like "svn not found" or "git not found". After digging a littile deeper , I saw that when ever I hit this scenario the value of PATH variable in Job "Environment Variable" is different then what I have set above.Like this:
[image]
Now , to solve this I even tried to disconnect the slave and reconnect , which only solves the problem temporarily. I came accross [this](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/229724088-How-To-Set-Up-A-Jenkins-Agent-To-Have-The-Same-Path-As-The-User-When-Connected-Via-Remote-Desktop) article too suggested to change the flag “PermitUserEnvironment” in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to “yes” and then restarting the sshd service. I followed these steps and it fixed the issues for an hour until it occurred again. What might be causing this? I also have envinject plugin on my master , can that be causing this issue? However when I run this job only on master it runs fine.
I am using cloud bees Jenkins.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find solution to this?

Comment: this was because of the env inject plugin. We just removed that.

Comment: We're having the same issue, but don't have envinject - I'll update here if i come across what is causing the issue.